# Azure Time trigger function - Getting error- No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000

Tags: c#, azure-functions

[image]

My Azure Time trigger function

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        }
}
```

1. I have clean %Temp% and Temp folder.
2. Restarted my machine.
3. StorageEmulator is runnig
4. I have Change port in
   "StorageEmulatorConfig"

**From**

```
<StorageEmulatorConfig>
    <services>
      <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
      <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
      <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
    </services>
```

**To**

```
<StorageEmulatorConfig>
    <services>
      <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:30001/"/>
      <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:30002/"/>
      <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:30003/"/>
    </services>
```

Comment: Have you set your AzureWebJobsStorage connection string to match the new ports you specified?

Comment: @juunas could you suggest how to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have specified different ports from the default, the connection string `UseDevelopmentStorage=True` will not work.

You will instead have to specify the full connection string manually in local.settings.json:

```json
{
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:30001/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:30002/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:30003/devstoreaccount1;"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) suggested, make sure azurite is running on your computer. If you are running it integrated from Visual studio you should find in the Output window by showing output from "Service Dependencies". Otherwise you can also run it from PowerShell or the VS Code extension.